# Can I make a function that makes a dataframe like this using loops? (follow up question)

Tags: dataframe, function, loops, sample

Thank you for your interest in this question.

I have the data as below.

```
a<- data.frame("Grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 4), "Prob"=c(0.01, 0.25, 0.45, 0.29))
b<- data.frame("Pot"= c(letters[1:18]))
```

Based on the codes below, I'd like to make a function that can loop 4 Grade numbers based on the Prob probability (replace=TRUE) and four random letters with the same probability (replace=FALSE). For instance, this loop may look like below:

```
3 2 3 2 d f k g
1 3 4 2 a k r b
```

I'd like to make a function that can compute not only the results in which the Grades result is only lower than 3, and the four alphabets that I selected appear, but the number of trials to get this result. So, if I want Pot to have "a", "b", "c", and "d" the result will look like:

```
 Trial Grade   Pot
15    3 2 1 3  a b c d
39    2 1 2 2  d b a c
2     3 3 3 3  d a b d
77    3 2 3 3  c d b a
```

I could learn the below code thanks to a very kind person, but I can't edit it to get the results I hope to see. Can you please help me?

```
     samplefun <- function(a) {
      c <- sample(a$Grade, size=4, prob=a$Prob, replace=TRUE)
      
      res <- tibble(
        Trial = which(c < 3)[1],
        Result = c[which(c < 3)[1]]
      )
nsamples <- 1000
x<-map_dfr(1:nsamples, ~ samplefun(a))
```

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: If you try to sample `b$Pot` using probabilities in `a$Prob`, an error occurs because the length of `a$Prob` doesn't match up to `b$Pot`. Could you supply another column of probabilities in data frame `b`, or modify your question to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to what I think you're after. I haven't specified a probability vector when sampling `b$Pot`, because you didn't give one that was 18 elements long in your question (see my comment).

```
library(tidyverse)

a<- data.frame(Grade =c(1, 2, 3, 4), Prob = c(0.01, 0.25, 0.45, 0.29))
b<- data.frame(Pot = letters[1:18])

chosenletters <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

samplefun <- function(a, b, chosenletters) {
  ntrials <- 0
  
  repeat {
    grades <- sample(a$Grade, size = 4, prob = a$Prob, replace = T)
    chars <- sample(b$Pot, size = 4, replace = F)
    ntrials <- ntrials + 1
    
    if (all(grades < 4) & all(chars %in% chosenletters)) {break}
  }
  
  return( tibble(Trial = ntrials, Grade = list(grades), Letters = list(chars)) )
}

nsamples <- 5
res <- map_dfr(1:nsamples, ~ samplefun(a, b, chosenletters))
```

This dataframe `res` gives the correct Grades and Letters embedded in lists inside each dataframe cell, plus the trial at which the result was generated.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Trial Grade     Letters  
  <dbl> <list>    <list>   
1 20863 <dbl [4]> <fct [4]>
2  8755 <dbl [4]> <fct [4]>
3 15129 <dbl [4]> <fct [4]>
4  1033 <dbl [4]> <fct [4]>
5  5264 <dbl [4]> <fct [4]>
```

A better view of the nested lists:

```
> glimpse(res)
Rows: 5
Columns: 3
$ Trial   <dbl> 20863, 8755, 15129, 1033, 5264
$ Grade   <list> <3, 3, 3, 3>, <3, 2, 2, 2>, <3, 3, 2, 2>, <3, 3, 2, 3>, <3, 2, 3, 3>
$ Letters <list> <b, a, c, d>, <b, a, c, d>, <c, a, b, d>, <b, d, c, a>, <a, b, d, c>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. For the probability for  'b$pot' yes the probabilities are just one/the number of letters, so your method is the right one I'm looking for. Again, thank you very much for answering another question. Can I ask where you studied or learned these? I'm very eager to learn more about this. I also saw your profile and learned that you are a PhD student. I'm a PhD student as well! Good luck!
(The questions are not related to any of my studies or work. They are just my pure curiosities..thank you!)

Comment: Great, no worries, glad it was useful again! I mostly learned R practically through using it as part of my research and learning from supervisors/peers along the way, though I've read about it and spent plenty of time learning it in my free time too. I'd recommend reading [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html), and doing some small projects, and then going onto [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) if you want to dig deeper. Thanks, and good luck with your PhD studies too!

Comment: Thank you so much Roy! I will start to study this. Have a wonderful day!